# Как исправить битые ссылки элементов фильтра при активации плагина транслитерации ссылок Cyr to Lat?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Есть сайт на **wordpress** в теме которого предусмотрен фильтр для поиска по определенным *testimonials*, к примеру портфолио каких-либо объектов.
Если добавить его на определенную страницу, то сама страница будет выводится в таком виде:

`http://сайт/?page_id=1234`

а элемент портфолио вот так -

`http://сайт/?portfolio_page=mnogostranichnyj-lending`

Если активировать [плагин транслитерации ссылок Cyr to Lat](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/cyr3lat/), то на сами страницы переход есть, а на элементах фильтра получаются битые ссылки. 
Как это исправить?

Comment: Чем/как сделано порфолио? И покажите такую страницу

Comment: @SeVlad вот таким образом
http://preview.themeforest.net/item/subway-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/5898023

Comment: Предлагаете купить тему, что бы помочь? Но даже это не поможет. Покажите РЕАЛЬНЫЕ ссылки на порфолио на вашем сайте

Comment: @SeVlad вся фишка в том, что, если задавать в настройках ссылки вида http://likemedia.by/?p=123, то страница содержащая фильтр выводится с классом `<body class="page">` и каждая ссылка элемента в таком виде http://likemedia.by/?portfolio_page=mnogostranichnyj-lending
а, если задавать произвольные ссылки вида http://likemedia.by/%postname%/, то уже выводится содержащая страница с классом `<body class="archive">` и ссылкой http://likemedia.by/portfolio с **no items**, а каждый элемент в таком виде: http://likemedia.by/portfolio_page/mnogostranichnyj-lending
почему вдруг так?

Comment: Ну понятно, что при изменении правил пермалинков адреса меняются. На то они и ЧПУ. Никаких параметров в адресах не будет. Что же до адреса likemedia.by/?portfolio_page=mnogostranichnyj-lending так такой страницы нет в принципе. Не удивительно, что 404. А вот likemedia.by/portfolio_page/mnogostranichnyj-lending-dlya-ooo-riterna я уверен - будет.

Comment: @SeVlad да, обрезалась ссылка при вставке.вопрос в том почему при изменении правил пермалинков адреса меняются настолько, что у страницы меняется класс вместо `<body class="page">` выводится `<body class="archive">`, соответственно подменяется шаблон отображения в котором выводится пусто и только надпись **no items** а сама страница называется archive

Comment: Шаблон меняться не должен. И плагин транслитерации тут точно не причём. К тому  нет у вас `<body class="page">` на странице одиночного портфолио. Есть `<body class="single single-portfolio_page ...`. Включите сейчас ЧПУ - я посмотрю что меняется.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51944/discussion-between--and-sevlad).

Comment: @SeVla посмотрели? я вам в чате ответил